# Are table member functions allowed to have no parameters?

Tags: lua, associative-array

The following Agena code will give a segmentation fault sometimes (about 50% of the time) after it prints 'will i crash?'

```
tbl := []

proc tbl@@test() is
    print('will i crash?')
end

tbl@@test()
```

However, if I declare a parameter to the function test, as shown below, it doesn't crash.

```
tbl := []

proc tbl@@test(_) is
    print('will i crash?')
end

tbl@@test()
```

In this example, _ is null when I try to print it. Does anyone know why the first code causes segmentation faults? And what should I do to avoid it? (other than put useless parameters all over the place)

P.S. I tagged this with `lua` as well since the `Agena` tag doesn't exist and I don't have enough rep to create it, and Agena takes most of its concepts from Lua

Comment: Someone should create "agena" tag (and retag this question).  Segfaults in Agena implementation are irrelevant to Lua.

Comment: BTW, there is a [forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/agena/forum/Agena/)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff ye i know, but its not very active. i asked there as well